# How to calculate time difference considering day light saving?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I have function which calculated time difference between two dates in milliseconds. I am getting the time just before 1 hour of day light saving starts and then calculating time after 5 minutes of it. I is giving me 5 minutes of difference, One hour getting skipped. Do anyone having idea?

Comment: Can you please include your code and the input dates, along with your actual and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

Suppose date1 is 20.03.2016, 13:00
date2 is 21.03.2016, 17:00

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Hour_of_day,13);
cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal2.set(Hour_of_day,17);
cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 21);
```

then difference of two gives time in milliseconds.

```
long time_in_milli = cal2.getTimeInMillis()-cal1.getTimeInMillis();
```

This would already take into account the day light saving thing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by including timezone with date ex: Format your date with timezone like - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" and then calculate time difference.